# Polynomial Functions

Tags: geometry, polynomials

Give the name (Monomial,Binomial,Trinomial, etc.) and degree of the polynomial

$4x^5+3x^3-7x$

Name : ?
Degree: ?

Can anyone help figure out what kind of polynomial this equation is? And what it means by degree?

Comment: This is not an equation, it is an expression.

Answer (score 2):

The degree is the  power of the monomial with the highest exponent.

In this case, the degree of this function is  $5.$

This has three terms, so it is a Trinomial.

The polynomial $7x^6 + 9$ has degree $6$ and is a Binomial.

The polynomial $8x^4 - 4x^{11} + 7x^3$ has degree $11$ and is a Trinomial.

Answer (score 0):

Degree - In functions of a single variable, such as x, the degree of a term is simply the highest exponent.

In this question degree is 5.

If we have single term then monomial, two terms then binomial and trinomial for three terms.

In this question three terms so trinomial.